# How to fill n random rows after filtering in polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm thinking for over a few hours how to fill n rows after filtering in polars with some value.

To give you an example, I'd like to do the following operation in polars.

Given a dataframe with column `a` that have `1`s and `2`s, we want to create column `b` that:

- Has `True` if `1` in column `a`.
- Has the same number of `True` as number of `1`s in column `a` for `2`s in column `a`. This is kind of stratification. Rows to receive `True` should be random.
- The rest of the rows in `b` has value `False`.

This is how I can do it in pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
})
df

    a
0   2
1   2
2   2
3   1
4   2
5   1
```

```py
n = df.shape[0]
n_1 = df['a'].value_counts()[1]
n_2 = n - n_1

df['b'] = False
df.loc[df['a'] == 1, 'b'] = True

idx = df.loc[df['a'] == 2].index[np.random.choice(n_2, n_1, replace=False)]
df.loc[idx, "b"] = True
df

    a   b
0   2   False
1   2   False
2   2   True
3   1   True
4   2   True
5   1   True
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I recommend avoiding "index"-type strategies, as they tend to be slow and inefficient.  Also, we want to avoid sorting and re-sorting large datasets, particularly if they have lots of columns.

So instead, what we'll do is construct column `b` separately from the original DataFrame, and then insert the finished column `b` into the original DataFrame.

Since you are transitioning from Pandas, I'll walk through how we'll do this in Polars, and print the results at each step.  (For your final solution, you can combine many of these intermediate steps and eliminate the implicit print statements after each step.)

##### Data

I'm going to expand your dataset, so that it has more columns than is strictly needed.  This will show us how to isolate the columns we need, and how to put the final result back into your DataFrame.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "c": ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'],
    "d": [6.0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
})
df
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c     ┆ d   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ one   ┆ 6.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ two   ┆ 5.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ three ┆ 4.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ four  ┆ 3.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ five  ┆ 2.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ six   ┆ 1.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ seven ┆ 0.0 │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
```

##### Constructing column `b`

First, we'll create a new DataFrame using only column `a` and add row numbers to track the original position of each element.  We'll then sort the `1s` to the bottom - we'll see why in a moment.

```py
df_a = df.select('a').with_row_count().sort('a', reverse=True)
df_a
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌────────┬─────┐
│ row_nr ┆ a   │
│ ---    ┆ --- │
│ u32    ┆ i64 │
╞════════╪═════╡
│ 0      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 1   │
└────────┴─────┘
```

Next we'll count the `1s` and `2s` using the `value_counts` method, which creates a new DataFrame with the results.

```py
values = df_a.get_column('a').value_counts().sort('a')
values
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ counts │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 5      │
└─────┴────────┘
```

So we have two `1s` and five `2s`.  We'll create two variables with this information that we'll use later.

```py
nr_1, nr_2 = values.get_column('counts')
print(f"{nr_1=}", f"{nr_2=}")
```

```
>>> print(f"{nr_1=}", f"{nr_2=}")
nr_1=2 nr_2=5
```

Now we'll construct the top part of `b`, which corresponds to the five `2s`.  We'll need three `False` and two `True` values.  We'll use the [`shuffle`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Series.shuffle.html) method to randomly shuffle the values.  (You can set the `seed=` value according to your needs.)

```py
b = (
    pl.repeat(True, nr_1, eager=True)
    .extend_constant(False, nr_2 - nr_1)
    .shuffle(seed=37)
)
b
```

```
shape: (5,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
        true
        false
        false
        false
        true
]
```

Now let's extend `b` with the two `True` values that correspond to the `1s` (that we previously sorted to the bottom of our `df_a` DataFrame.)

```py
b = b.extend_constant(True, nr_1)
b
```

```
shape: (7,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
        true
        false
        false
        false
        true
        true
        true
]
```

And we'll add this column to our `df_a`, to see how the values of `a` and `b` align.

```py
df_a = df_a.select([
    pl.all(),
    b.alias("b")]
)
df_a
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ a   ┆ b     │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ bool  │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 2   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 2   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 2   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 1   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 1   ┆ true  │
└────────┴─────┴───────┘
```

We see that our two `1s` at the bottom of column `a` both correspond to a `True` value in `b`.  And we see that two of the `2s` in column `a` correspond to `True` values, while the remaining values are `False`.

##### Adding column `b` back to our original DataFrame

All that's left to do is restore the original sort order, and insert column `b` into our original DataFrame.

```py
df_a = df_a.sort("row_nr")
df = df.select([
    pl.all(),
    df_a.get_column("b")
])
df
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ c     ┆ d   ┆ b     │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ f64 ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 2   ┆ one   ┆ 6.0 ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ two   ┆ 5.0 ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ three ┆ 4.0 ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ four  ┆ 3.0 ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ five  ┆ 2.0 ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ six   ┆ 1.0 ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ seven ┆ 0.0 ┆ true  │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴───────┘
```

##### Simplifying

If your original DataFrame is not large, you don't need to create a separate `df_a` -- you can sort (and re-sort) the original DataFrame.  (But once your datasets get large, unnecessarily sorting lots of additional columns at each step can slow your computations.)

Also, you can combine many of the intermediate steps, as you see fit.